# Which headers indicate a request for static assets

Tags: node.js, http, express, http-headers

Using Express we see middleware like so:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + '/public')));

app.use('/', function(req,res,next){
  // if we get here, the request was not for static assets
});
```

my question is - **which headers does Express use** to check that the request is for static assets (files, etc)?

I want to replicate some middleware that does what Express does for static assets.

Comment: Express uses this package to serve static assets: https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical HTTP request does not have any special headers that suggest that a client might be requesting a static asset over something else. In fact, there is concept of a 'static asset' in HTTP. HTTP is completely obviously to an asset being static, or not.

Anything can be 'static' or 'dynamic'. The middleware probably works because it will check the filesystem if a file exists.